# $\sum_{2n\le x}\phi(2n)$

Tags: summation, totient-function

We know that, denoting with $\phi$ the Euler's function we have
$$
\sum_{n\le x}\phi(n) \sim \frac{3}{\pi^2}x^2.
$$

What is the same asymptotic formula for
$$
\sum_{2n\le x}\phi(2n)\,\,\,?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a fudge and would benefit from some tidying up!

Let
$$
S(x) = \sum_{n\space odd, n\le x}\phi(n)
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{n\le x}\phi(n) = S(x) + \sum_{2||n, n\le x}\phi(n) + \sum_{4||n, n\le x}\phi(n) + ...
$$
where the sums terminate with the largest power of $2$ that is less than $x$.

This is simple to rewrite in terms of $S$
$$
\sum_{n\le x}\phi(n) = S(x) + S({x\over2}) + 2S({x\over4}) + 4S({x\over8}) +...
$$
Now the fudge. Let's assume $S(x)$ is asymptotically quadratic, i.e. 
$$
S(x) = kx^2 + o(x^2)
$$
Substituting we obtain
$$
{3\over k \pi^2} = 1 + {1\over 4} + {1\over 8} + {1\over 16} + ... = {3\over 2}
$$
So $k = 2/\pi^2$ and 
$$
S(x) = {2\over \pi^2}x^2 + o(x^2)
$$
To complete, 
$$
\sum_{2n\le x} \phi(2n) = \sum_{n\le x} \phi(n) - S(x) = {x^2 \over \pi^2} + o(x^2)
$$

Okay, I did some pretty bad things here. I don't feel too bad about the convergence of the geometric series - even though I should have been more careful it's fairly obvious that any residue will be $o(x^2)$. The really bad bit is assuming the quadratic asymptote. If anyone can justify that please add to the post.

Comment: That is perfect, since I know how to prove that it is a quadratic, but I couldn't find the constant! For the formal proof, you may end up evaluting an infinite sum of the form $\sum_{n\ge 1}\mu(2n-1)/n^2$.. Do you know what's the result of this sum?

Comment: Well, by indirect method (using your solution), that sum should be, again, $2/\pi^2$ :)

Comment: I agree with @Nduccio, and there are grounds to be cautious here. The sum accumulates a lot of $o(x^2)$ terms, which really should be expressed as $O(x(log x)^{2/3}(log log x)^{4/3})$

Comment: It's trivial to extend this to other divisors, Struck by the observation that the even terms only contribute 1/3 of the series in $\phi$, I've just done the calculation for other primes. In general, the multiples of a prime $p$ contribute $1\over{2p+1}$ of the series.